# nodejs pbkdf2sync Not a buffer error

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, cryptography

Suddenly in my console it's start giving errors, and it has been running fine for days without any change. Please advise.

```
/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:82
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Not a buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:607:20)
    at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:590:10)


    crypto: require("crypto"),

    encrypt: function(password) {
        var salt = this.getSalt(password, this.constructor.GUID);
        return {salt: salt, password: this.getEncrypted(password, salt)};
    },

    getSalt: function(password, GUID) {
        return this.crypto.createHash("sha256").update(password + "|" + GUID).digest("hex")
    },

    getEncrypted: function(password, salt) {
        return this.crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 4096, 512, "sha256").toString("hex");
    },

    verifyPassword: function(user, password) { //var salt = this.getSalt("test@test.com|" + this.constructor.GUID); console.log("salt: " + salt); console.log("password: " + this.getPassword("HUG2015", salt));
        return this.crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, user.salt, 4096, 512, "sha256").toString("hex")  == user.password; //test
    },

    generateAuthToken: function() {
        return this.crypto.randomBytes(64).toString("hex");
    }
```

**Edit: Usage**

```
        getUser: function(emailAddress, password) {
            var self = this;
            this.connection.query("SELECT * from admin WHERE emailAddress = ?", [emailAddress], function(error, rows, fields){
                if(error) {
                    self.onFault({status: 500, body: error});
                } else {
                    if(rows.length == 1) {
                        self.verifyPassword(rows[0], password)
                    } else {
                        self.onFault({status: 401, body: {}});
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        verifyPassword: function(user, password) {
            var self = this;
            try {
                if(this.authenticationProxy.verifyPassword(user, password)) {
                    this.setAuthToken(user, this.authenticationProxy.generateAuthToken());
                } else {
                    this.onFault({status: 401, body: {}});
                }
            } catch(exception) {
                this.onFault({status:500, body: exception});
            }
        },
```

Comment: I've editing with the usage

Comment: That doesn't help much. Which line are you talking about? Can you show example inputs? Can you create a full example outside of your own code?

Comment: hmmm trying my best, the error is at line `return this.crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 4096, 512, "sha256").toString("hex");`

Comment: at minimum, can you please tell me if the strategy is good or should I be changing something incorrect here?

Comment: Make sure password is not null.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is, that 'not a buffer' is thrown if *password* is a number. Inside crypto.js there is a *toBuf* call which tries to change *password* into a buffer (unless it is already a buffer) but converts Strings only.

You can try two things:

1) ensure that password (passed to `crypto.pbkdf2Sync`) is a String

2) or convert it to buffer yourself -> pass `new Buffer(password, 'binary')`

Comment: I've not tried it since it came very late but it seems promising but answer accepted.

Comment: I have the same issue, but the password definitely isn't a number. Why would this error be appearing in that case?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your code sample :)

Answer (score 1):

If this code hasn't changed at all and suddenly it's not working, it's because one of the calling libraries or other changes you have made are interfering.

(Or a new node version is being used, but I doubt that's your problem).

The pattern you are using is not recommended:

```
mysingleton = {

crypto: require('crypto'),
...

}
```

This is because any callback through an anonymous function will lose your 'this' Object.

Also in node.js, you do not need this pattern, because each file in mode.js is kept in a separate namespace and protected by the module.exports.

You can get rid of the references to 'this' in the following way, as a quick check to see if 'this' is the culprit:

```
var
   c = require('crypto');

mysingleton = {

// delete the crypto definition here
// crypto: ...,
...
encrypt: function(password) {
    // note elimination of this below
    var salt = mysingleton.getSalt(password, this.constructor.GUID);
    return {salt: salt, password: this.getEncrypted(password, salt)};
},
...
getSalt: function(password, GUID) {
    return c.createHash("sha256").update(password + "|" + GUID).digest("hex")
},
...
}
```

If that fixes things, I would suggest you get some more background on what the best recommended pattern is for your framework / system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to send the JSON object directly to the function.

```
{ token: "abc" }
```

I stringify the input to the function and everything worked properly.

```
JSON.stringify({ token: "abc" })
```